# The GET method is not supported for route logout. Supported methods: POST in laravel when manually type logout in url

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, logout

My laravel version is 9.19. When I click on logout menu its working fine.
But when I manually type 'logout' in url it gives the error - The GET method is not supported for route logout. Supported methods: POST.

[image]

It shows as a POST route in route:list:

```
POST logout .............. logout › Auth\LoginController@logout
```

in web.php:

```
Auth::routes( [ 'register' => false ] );
```

How can i solve this in case of manually type 'logout' in url?

Comment: it isn't a `GET` route, it is a `POST` route ... there is no reason to type in a URL to logout and it shouldn't be a simple link, causing a `GET` request ... there is good reason for this being a `POST` route

Comment: Either use logout as POST request OR do `Route::get(...logout class here@method)` in your auth.php or wherever your logout route is located.

Comment: Though it is better to use POST request for logout as per what @lagbox said!

Comment: having said all of that, if you really wanted to you could create a `GET` route that points to that same action on that controller as stated by Mr.Kenneth, just don't put it into production with that route existing

Comment: Why would you, or anyone, manually type the URL?

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution, added this into my web.php

```
Route::get('/logout', function () {
    Auth::logout();
    return redirect()->route('login');
})->name('logout');
```